# How do I keep a static URL in GitHub for my Adguard home blocklist?

Tags: github

I noticed the provided blocklists for Adguard Home were from GitHub. I am trying to make my own list and reference it to GitHub. I am a noob at this. I basically made the code and pushed it to GitHub. Adguard Home needs a link to the code so in GitHub I click on raw and it open a new tab and I copy the URL to AGH, however the link is dynamic and when my AGH looks for it again for updates, nothing is there. I know this because the ads aren't being blocked and the link goes to a 404 error. How do I make the URL to the GitHub text file static?

Comment: Can you provide an example URL? Are you including the commit or blob hash, or using a branch?

Comment: So I was able to get the AGH to read the GitHub code by making it go public. my new question is if its possible for AGH to read the code without going public. Sorry for the new question. forgot to get back to this question here. I asked on reddit but no one has responded yet.